# Arduino dual can bus message resend

Tags: c++, arduino, can-bus

I have an Arduino and two mcp2515 modules, integrated into two can network. My task is to a receive package from CAN1 change some bytes and send it to CAN2. Also, do the same for CAN2 read & change & send to CAN1. But I was faced with the issue when I send from CAN1 to CAN2 packages, and then read CAN2 I'll get only which what I was sent from CAN1.

Does somebody know how to handle this case?

I theory it should work but no. Does there any other way to handle it except a memorize "what I did send already"?

```
#include <mcp_can.h>

unsigned char carDataBuffer[8];
unsigned char pdcDataBuffer[8];

unsigned char carLength;
unsigned char pdcLength;


MCP_CAN CAN_CAR(10);
MCP_CAN CAN_PDC(5);


void initCanBus() {
  while (CAN_CAR.begin(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHz) != CAN_OK) {}
  while (CAN_PDC.begin(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_8MHz) != CAN_OK) {}
}

void setup() {
  initCanBus();
}

void loop() {
  if (CAN_CAR.checkReceive() == CAN_MSGAVAIL) {
    CAN_CAR.readMsgBuf(&carLength, carDataBuffer);
    unsigned long  carAddress = CAN_CAR.getCanId();

    CAN_PDC.sendMsgBuf(carAddress, 0, 8, carDataBuffer);
  }

  if (CAN_PDC.checkReceive() == CAN_MSGAVAIL) {
    CAN_PDC.readMsgBuf(&pdcLength, pdcDataBuffer);
    unsigned long  pdcAddress = CAN_PDC.getCanId();

    CAN_CAR.sendMsgBuf(pdcAddress, 0, 8, pdcDataBuffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Arduino is completely unsuitable for this project. You should be using a MCU with two CAN controllers on-chip.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for the comment. Do you have some examples?

Comment: I would think most Cortex M families have parts with 2 CAN controllers.